# Android - SharedPreference converting to Double

Tags: android, string, double, sharedpreferences

Basically i have a valued saved into shared preference as a string.

I am retrieving the value saved, and am trying to use it in a calculation.

How can i convert this so that it is seen as a double instead of a string?

Once the value is retrieved after the calculation, the new value is saved back into the sharedpreference under the same value.

I hope you can understand, been having trouble with this!

```
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            String newweight =  sharedPreferences.getString("storednewweight", "");
            newweight = newweight + 5;
            //saves value into sharedpreference
            savePreferences("storednewweight", (Double.toString(newweight)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [parse the string as a double](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)):

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

String weight =  sharedPreferences.getString("storednewweight", "");
Double newweight = Double.parseDouble(weight);
newweight = newweight + 5;

//saves value into sharedpreference
savePreferences("storednewweight", (Double.toString(newweight)));
```

Comment: Yeah i did it like this, i used two different variables.

Answer (score 0):

It can be saved as long like how I wrote it down:

**Double to Long:**

```
Double.doubleToRawLongBits(double);
```

**Long to Double:**

```
Double.longBitsToDouble(defaultLongValue);
```

**EDIT:**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
Long newweightTemp =  sharedPreferences.getLong("storednewweight", 0L);
Double newWeight = Double.longBitsToDouble(newweightTemp );
newweight = newweight + 5;
//saves value into sharedpreference
sharedPreferences.edit().putLong("storednewweight", Double.doubleToRawLongBits(newWeight)).apply();
```

Something like that should do it.

Comment: Getting an error on the last line, says it cannot be applied.

Comment: I just took your code and implemented the correct implementation. Look on the edit

Answer (score 0):

> How can i convert this so that it is seen as a double instead of a
>   string?

A) If you don't need the double precision, use floats: [getFloat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getFloat(java.lang.String,%20float)) and [putFloat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putFloat(java.lang.String,%20float)).

B) [Parse the string as a double](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)) then [save the double as a string](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)) again.

Comment: Ive worked out another way, ive just used new variables, this or other way works.