# How can i use putdouble instead of put int

Tags: java, android, casting, sharedpreferences

I wanna save the value of my textview in a `onstop` and `onpause`. But the value that is in the `textview` is a `double`, how can cast `putint` to `double` or use something else for it

This is my code
How can i solve this?

```
     @Override
        protected void onStop()
        {
            super.onStop();
            savedValues.edit().putInt("price", (double)price).apply();
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't put double SharedPreferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319237/cant-put-double-sharedpreferences)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28309536/2308683

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try storing a [float](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putFloat(java.lang.String,%20float)) but if loosing the precision is an Killing issue then consider storing that as String by calling the method [putString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

```
 putString (String key, String value)
```

and then parse that into a double

```
Double.parseDouble(myValueAsString);
```

Comment: @Override
        protected void onStop()
        {
            super.onStop();
            savedValues.edit().putInt("price",Double.parseDouble(myValueAsString);.apply();
        }
like this ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 savedValues.edit().putString("price",Double.parseDouble(price)).apply();
```

Comment: parseDouble returns double, which can't be used with `putString`

Comment: it says Double cannot applied to java.long,Double

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.