# Convert String from Shared Preferences to Double Value

Tags: android, string, double, sharedpreferences

I've been trying to convert the following string to double value from my Shared Preferences key but still failed even I've tried to follow the solution from the previous Q&A ([Android - SharedPreference converting to Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28309460/android-sharedpreference-converting-to-double))

Here are my code:

```
String strCurr_Lat = FM_SharePrefs.getString("FM_Curr_Lat", "");
String strCurr_Lng = FM_SharePrefs.getString("FM_Curr_Lng", "");
String strDest_Lat = FM_SharePrefs.getString("FM_Dest_Lat", "");
String strDest_Lng = FM_SharePrefs.getString("FM_Dest_Lng", "");

Double dCurr_Lat = Double.parseDouble(strCurr_Lat);
```

Failed and throw an error when reach the assign double variable.
Can anyone assist? Thank you very much.

-sea-

Comment: Share your error log?

Comment: Are you certain that these values were actually saved into shared preferences?

Comment: It's latitude coordinate I save in the previous activity.

Comment: Yes TimBiegeleisen. It's displayed when I used Toast command.

Comment: Mention the values of each variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parse in `double` your string need to in floating number formate. So first you have to check whether it is or not , Otherwise it will throw `NumberFormatException` .

```
String strCurr_Lat = FM_SharePrefs.getString("FM_Curr_Lat", "");
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(strCurr_Lat)){
        try {
            Double curr_Lat = Double.parseDouble(strCurr_Lat);
        }catch (NumberFormatException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Parse","String not in floating format");
        }
    }
```

Comment: My mistake, i add some text string in front of the value of the coordinate so it becomes "lat=x.xxx". Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
Double dCurr_Lat = Double.valueOf(strCurr_Lat);
```

Answer (score 0):

if your value is not null then try this it will work.

```
double dCurr_Lat= Double.parseDouble(strCurr_Lat);
```